# VirtualUriMapping doesn´t function- Magnolia CMS

Tags: url, module, components, freemarker, magnolia

I´m trying to transform my Url according to Magnolia documentation: 
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/URI+mapping#URImapping-URItorepositorymapping

I need to change my language page:

I receive this:

```
http://localhost:8080/module/en/TEST_/newsdetails/201602151
```

With this sentence:

```
<a href="${cpathx}/${cmsfn.language()}/${rootPage}/newsdetails/${encodeTitle!""}">
```

And I´m transforming by UriMapping to this:

```
http://localhost:8080/module/en/TEST_/newsdetails?newsRef=201602151
```

I don´t know when i do the URIMapping it doesn´t show in my language 'EN', only shows the language by default and doesn´t get the 'EN'

This´s my URIMapping:

[image: URIMAPPING]

and this is my site definition config: 
[image]

The problem is when i do:

```
${cmsfn.language()}
```

It returns my language by default..

Also I,ve tried putting this URiMapping: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need locale aware VirtualURIMapping - see Matteo Pelucco's blog post: http://maips21.altervista.org/wordpress/2015/05/05/how-to-build-a-locale-aware-virtualurimapping-in-magnolia-with-regexp/